# Modifying Android systrace for capturing CPU Frequency even where is no change

Tags: android, cpu-usage, systrace, ftrace

I am currently running systrace with the category "freq" to capture cpu frequency with my device and I noticed that it only outputs something during a change in the freq. So if there was no change during the capture, the html output that systrace spits out will be blank. I would like to modify the atrace function and show cpu frequency even if there is no change. I was thinking of reading cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq in adb shell and simulating a change to say it changed from 0 to the current so it could at least output something. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some fake ftrace messages into the systrace's html output. So if you add some fake cpu-freq event message which contains the unique(zero?) value near the beginning of the trace texts in the output html file, you'll see cpu freq line in the systrace output screen.